# Setting SVG color in CSS to cover the whole background

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a set of social media icons in SVG format and I am using height and width attributes of 2em. But my background color is not white. I was thinking that it's not a problem until I tried to solve the problem by setting the background color of the SVG. For some reason, the background of the SVG is not the whole SVG, but a part of it. You can see it in the snippet. Maybe it has something to do with `viewBox='0 0 24 24'` attribute of the SVG. Is it possible to set background to match 2em x 2em - just like the size of the SVG I set?

Without white background, SVGs don't look very pretty.

**Update:** I've changed the code a little bit compared to the initial version. It looks like this now:

```css
body {background: rgba(78, 192, 253, .7);}
.tg:before {
    content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='2em' height='2em' fill='rgb(0, 136, 204)' viewBox='0 0 24 24' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xml:space='preserve' xmlns:serif='http://www.serif.com/' style='fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.41421;'%3E%3Cpath fill='white' d='M19,24l-14,0c-2.761,0 -5,-2.239 -5,-5l0,-14c0,-2.761 2.239,-5 5,-5l14,0c2.762,0 5,2.239 5,5l0,14c0,2.761 -2.238,5 -5,5Z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M19,24l-14,0c-2.761,0 -5,-2.239 -5,-5l0,-14c0,-2.761 2.239,-5 5,-5l14,0c2.762,0 5,2.239 5,5l0,14c0,2.761 -2.238,5 -5,5Zm-2.744,-5.148c0.215,0.153 0.491,0.191 0.738,0.097c0.246,-0.093 0.428,-0.304 0.483,-0.56c0.579,-2.722 1.985,-9.614 2.512,-12.09c0.039,-0.187 -0.027,-0.381 -0.173,-0.506c-0.147,-0.124 -0.351,-0.16 -0.532,-0.093c-2.795,1.034 -11.404,4.264 -14.923,5.567c-0.223,0.082 -0.368,0.297 -0.361,0.533c0.008,0.235 0.167,0.44 0.395,0.509c1.578,0.471 3.65,1.128 3.65,1.128c0,0 0.967,2.924 1.472,4.41c0.063,0.187 0.21,0.334 0.402,0.384c0.193,0.05 0.397,-0.002 0.541,-0.138c0.811,-0.765 2.064,-1.948 2.064,-1.948c0,0 2.381,1.746 3.732,2.707Zm-7.34,-5.784l1.119,3.692l0.249,-2.338c0,0 4.324,-3.9 6.79,-6.124c0.072,-0.065 0.082,-0.174 0.022,-0.251c-0.06,-0.077 -0.169,-0.095 -0.251,-0.043c-2.857,1.825 -7.929,5.064 -7.929,5.064Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 0.25em;
    background-color: #fff;}
    
    .soc {
    padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="fs01">
                    <legend><a href="https://t.me/grolribasi" class="soc tg" target="_blank">@Grolribasi</a></legend>
                    <p class="soc">Text goes here</p>
                </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution to your problem is adding a white filled path to the svg element like so:

```css
body {background: rgba(78, 192, 253, .7);}
.soc:before {
    content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='2em' height='2em' fill='rgb(0, 136, 204)' viewBox='0 0 24 24' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xml:space='preserve' xmlns:serif='http://www.serif.com/' style='fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.41421;'%3E%3Cpath fill='white' d='M19,24l-14,0c-2.761,0 -5,-2.239 -5,-5l0,-14c0,-2.761 2.239,-5 5,-5l14,0c2.762,0 5,2.239 5,5l0,14c0,2.761 -2.238,5 -5,5Z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M19,24l-14,0c-2.761,0 -5,-2.239 -5,-5l0,-14c0,-2.761 2.239,-5 5,-5l14,0c2.762,0 5,2.239 5,5l0,14c0,2.761 -2.238,5 -5,5Zm-2.744,-5.148c0.215,0.153 0.491,0.191 0.738,0.097c0.246,-0.093 0.428,-0.304 0.483,-0.56c0.579,-2.722 1.985,-9.614 2.512,-12.09c0.039,-0.187 -0.027,-0.381 -0.173,-0.506c-0.147,-0.124 -0.351,-0.16 -0.532,-0.093c-2.795,1.034 -11.404,4.264 -14.923,5.567c-0.223,0.082 -0.368,0.297 -0.361,0.533c0.008,0.235 0.167,0.44 0.395,0.509c1.578,0.471 3.65,1.128 3.65,1.128c0,0 0.967,2.924 1.472,4.41c0.063,0.187 0.21,0.334 0.402,0.384c0.193,0.05 0.397,-0.002 0.541,-0.138c0.811,-0.765 2.064,-1.948 2.064,-1.948c0,0 2.381,1.746 3.732,2.707Zm-7.34,-5.784l1.119,3.692l0.249,-2.338c0,0 4.324,-3.9 6.79,-6.124c0.072,-0.065 0.082,-0.174 0.022,-0.251c-0.06,-0.077 -0.169,-0.095 -0.251,-0.043c-2.857,1.825 -7.929,5.064 -7.929,5.064Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<body>
<a href="https://t.me/grolribasi" class="soc tg" target="_blank">tg</a><br>
 <a href="https://t.me/grolribasi" class="soc" target="_blank">tg</a><br>
</body>
```

In order to get the right path I use the first part (from the begining to the first m command) of the d attribute from your code.

Explanation:

This is the SVG I'm using as a background.

```html
<svg width='2em' height='2em' fill='rgb(0, 136, 204)' viewBox='0 0 24 24' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xml:space='preserve' xmlns:serif='http://www.serif.com/' style='fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.41421;'>
  <path fill="white" d='M19,24l-14,0c-2.761,0 -5,-2.239 -5,-5l0,-14c0,-2.761 2.239,-5 5,-5l14,0c2.762,0 5,2.239 5,5l0,14c0,2.761 -2.238,5 -5,5Z'/>
  <path d='M19,24l-14,0c-2.761,0 -5,-2.239 -5,-5l0,-14c0,-2.761 2.239,-5 5,-5l14,0c2.762,0 5,2.239 5,5l0,14c0,2.761 -2.238,5 -5,5Z
           
        m-2.744,-5.148c0.215,0.153 0.491,0.191 0.738,0.097c0.246,-0.093 0.428,-0.304 0.483,-0.56c0.579,-2.722 1.985,-9.614 2.512,-12.09c0.039,-0.187 -0.027,-0.381 -0.173,-0.506c-0.147,-0.124 -0.351,-0.16 -0.532,-0.093c-2.795,1.034 -11.404,4.264 -14.923,5.567c-0.223,0.082 -0.368,0.297 -0.361,0.533c0.008,0.235 0.167,0.44 0.395,0.509c1.578,0.471 3.65,1.128 3.65,1.128c0,0 0.967,2.924 1.472,4.41c0.063,0.187 0.21,0.334 0.402,0.384c0.193,0.05 0.397,-0.002 0.541,-0.138c0.811,-0.765 2.064,-1.948 2.064,-1.948c0,0 2.381,1.746 3.732,2.707Zm-7.34,-5.784l1.119,3.692l0.249,-2.338c0,0 4.324,-3.9 6.79,-6.124c0.072,-0.065 0.082,-0.174 0.022,-0.251c-0.06,-0.077 -0.169,-0.095 -0.251,-0.043c-2.857,1.825 -7.929,5.064 -7.929,5.064Z'></svg>
```

The original path, the one you have in your code is a holed one. This is why you can see the blue background. If you need the plain to be white you need to use something white behind the hole. Normally a rect would do but you gave the rounded corners path and if you are using a rect you will see the white corners.

In my code I take the first part of the d attribute of your path and I'm using it to draw a white path with the same shape and put it behind the hole.

Next you need to encode it. The easiest way is using this svg encoder: https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/JDqvs

Comment: Great solution! But I've changed the code a little and it stopped working. See my original post. How does that white filled path works? Maybe I could solve it myself if I knew.

Comment: Thank you now it's more clear. I even managed to do it myself partially. However, I can't understand why is it not filling correctly when I have <fieldset> and <legend> tags. And when I tried filling this icon: https://iconmonstr.com/whatsapp-3-svg/ according to the method you have described it only filled the phone, but not the circle. And it also doesn't work with this one (there are no m commands) - https://iconmonstr.com/email-3-svg/.

Comment: If you have a problem when using  `<fieldset>` and `<legend>`please ask another question with an working example. Also I don't know how do you draw the  phone and the circle and I'can't give you an answer without seeing the code.

Answer (score -1):

The SVG that you insert in the link have no default size, you can add them to an element and control it's size, in order to set an svg background.

```css
body {background: rgba(78, 192, 253, .7);}

.soc {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
   border-radius: 8px;
}

.soc:before {
    content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='2em' height='2em' fill='rgb(0, 136, 204)' viewBox='0 0 24 24' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xml:space='preserve' xmlns:serif='http://www.serif.com/' style='fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.41421;'%3E%3Cpath id='telegram-3' d='M19,24l-14,0c-2.761,0 -5,-2.239 -5,-5l0,-14c0,-2.761 2.239,-5 5,-5l14,0c2.762,0 5,2.239 5,5l0,14c0,2.761 -2.238,5 -5,5Zm-2.744,-5.148c0.215,0.153 0.491,0.191 0.738,0.097c0.246,-0.093 0.428,-0.304 0.483,-0.56c0.579,-2.722 1.985,-9.614 2.512,-12.09c0.039,-0.187 -0.027,-0.381 -0.173,-0.506c-0.147,-0.124 -0.351,-0.16 -0.532,-0.093c-2.795,1.034 -11.404,4.264 -14.923,5.567c-0.223,0.082 -0.368,0.297 -0.361,0.533c0.008,0.235 0.167,0.44 0.395,0.509c1.578,0.471 3.65,1.128 3.65,1.128c0,0 0.967,2.924 1.472,4.41c0.063,0.187 0.21,0.334 0.402,0.384c0.193,0.05 0.397,-0.002 0.541,-0.138c0.811,-0.765 2.064,-1.948 2.064,-1.948c0,0 2.381,1.746 3.732,2.707Zm-7.34,-5.784l1.119,3.692l0.249,-2.338c0,0 4.324,-3.9 6.79,-6.124c0.072,-0.065 0.082,-0.174 0.022,-0.251c-0.06,-0.077 -0.169,-0.095 -0.251,-0.043c-2.857,1.825 -7.929,5.064 -7.929,5.064Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<body>
<a href="https://t.me/grolribasi" class="tg" target="_blank"><i class="soc"></i>tg</a><br>
 <a href="https://t.me/grolribasi" target="_blank"><i class="soc"></i>tg</a><br>
</body>
```

Comment: It works fine if you add width, height, and display. But you lose padding if you add width and height. If you remove those, you get some white background showing to the right and bottom of the icon. The white space to the right is actually padding-right: 0.25em; in :before. If you remove display property it gets even worse. Besides, I can't add :before to .soc because there different social network icons for each link.